# JavaFX Button prevent to contract

Tags: java, javafx

This is my app:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    ControlPane ctrlPane = new ControlPane(); //extends TitledPane and customize it
    LogViewPane lvPane = new LogViewPane("ChartName"); //extends TitledPane and customize it

    HBox hboxCtrl = new HBox(ctrlPane);
    hboxCtrl.setFillHeight(false);

    HBox hboxLV = new HBox(lvPane);
    hboxLV.setFillHeight(false);

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setFillWidth(false);

    VBox.setMargin(hboxCtrl, new Insets(5));
    VBox.setMargin(hboxLV, new Insets(0, 5, 5, 5));

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(hboxCtrl, hboxLV);

    ScrollPane mainScrollPanel = new ScrollPane();
    mainScrollPanel.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    mainScrollPanel.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    mainScrollPanel.setFitToHeight(true);
    mainScrollPanel.setFitToWidth(true);
    mainScrollPanel.setContent(vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainScrollPanel);
    //load css

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

This is LogViewPane:

```
public class LogViewPane extends TitledPane{

    public LogViewPane(String chartName){

        super("LOG", null);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TextField inputDate = new TextField();
        inputDate.setMinWidth(100);
        inputDate.setMaxWidth(100);

        Button buttonLog = new Button("LOG");
        Button buttonChart = new Button("CHART");

        HBox.setMargin(inputDate, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(buttonLog, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(buttonChart, new Insets(0));

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(inputDate, buttonLog, buttonChart);

        this.setCollapsible(false);
        this.setContent(hbox);

    }

}
```

My app looks ok, until I reduce size of window.

When I reduce size of window, buttons from LogViewPane contract.

Here is an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

How can I prevent buttons to contract when window size is to small?

Here is what I want:

[image]

Comment: What would you expect it to look like?

Comment: Like buttons from `Control`, with full text and `TitledPane(LOG)` to be outside of view on right side.

Comment: Can you draw it?

Comment: @JonathanRosenne I updated my question with an image.

Comment: And if the window size were to be reduced even further? Try not to set inputDate minimum width.

Comment: Now also inputDate is contracting.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne TitledPane should have the same size, doesn't matter size of window

Comment: I don't think you can have anything outside of the window.

Comment: Try setting the minWidth on both HBoxes.